# If need to make unregistration before re-registration GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I developing the application that use the GCM. As mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#reg-state), after the application update need to invalidate the existing registration ID and start the registration process again.

Does this mean that I need to make unregistration before making the new registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to unregister before registering again. In fact, in most cases, when you register again you will get the same Registration ID you had in your previous registration. By "invalidate the existing registration ID" they mean that after an application update, the app should clear the Registration ID it has stored locally and request a Registration ID from GCM again (by calling `GoogleCloudMessaging.register`).

If, however, you unregister and then register again, you increase the chances that GCM would assign the device a new Registration ID, which means you have to remove the old Registration ID from your server's DB (to avoid sending duplicate messages to the same device).